# Does using UEFI increase battery life?

Tags: power-management, laptop, gpt, uefi, battery

I've heard about a better power management when using UEFI instead of BIOS. Is that true? It was about energy consumption being more efficient or something like that.

If it is true, has the functionality been implemented in Linux yet? I mean, does a driver exist for that?

Do I have improved speed with a GPT-formatted disk or just a quicker boot due to my UEFI usage?

Answer (score 7):

UEFI has nothing to do with power management. ACPI manages power. UEFI indicates modern firmware than BIOS and newer platform, thus improved power efficiency. This might be a correlation.

The PM subsystem is different from UEFI. Linux includes a whole range of power management functionalities, though unrelated to UEFI, like cpufreq, intel_pstate, pcie_aspm, laptop_mode, pci_pm, usb autosuspend. You realize these options are related to specific devices instead of the platform firmware (UEFI).

You achieve the same speed with MBR formatted disk. Faster boot speed is because UEFI is capable of more computation and doing more optimized device initialization.